# Specify the criteria of the optimal solution

Tags: optimization

I have three variables $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ and a function $f :  D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $D$ is defined as such :

$$D = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$$ such that $$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=1$$ and $$x_{1}>x_{2}>x_{3}$$
Therefore, D is the intersection of a plane and a box, and hence is a plane.

The objective is to find $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \in D$ such as $f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) = c \in \mathbb{R}$. The function $f$ is injective and so for a fixed $c \in \mathbb{R}$, there can be multiple solutions  $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$. Among all the solutions, I want to find the one that has the highest $x_{1}$, and then once the highest $x_{1}$ is found, the highest $x_{2}$. How do I specify this constraint ?

Note that the function $f$ doesn't have a closed-form solution and I am using minimize from scipy to find the $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to find $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that:

- $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in D$
- $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = c$, where $c$ is a given parameter
- $x_1>x_2 >x_3$

Also, you want to maximize $x_1$ and $x_2$, but $x_1$ has "priority" over $x_2$. So you can use the following objective function:

$$
\max \; \omega_1 x_1 + \omega_2 x_2
$$

where $\omega_1$ is weight larger than $\omega_2$, e.g., $\omega_1 = 10 \omega_2$. Choosing adequate values for $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ depends on $D$.

Comment: In this case simply add the terms to your existing objective function.

Comment: EDIT : Sorry I made a mistake in the last comment. The objective function is rather $$\min f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})-c$$ so the transformed objective function would be $$\min f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})-c-\lambda (w_{1}x_{1}+w_{2}x_{2})$$ with $\lambda >0$. In this case, the heuristic choice of $\lambda$ makes the problem randomish, no ?

Comment: Why don't you add $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=c$ as a constraint ? Or if you cannot have the exact equality, $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) \le c +\varepsilon_1$, and $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) \ge c -\varepsilon_2$

Comment: I couldn't have the exact equality so my first intuition was to minimize the difference. But yes actually adding a small $\epsilon$ and adding it as a inequality constraint is a great idea and should work, thank you ! I'll try this out.

Comment: When I first heard of 'Operations Research Beta' I immediately thought to look you up, Kuifje!